# how to intstall mysql server on ubuntu

Tags: mysql

i am using ubuntu 15.10

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

output:

```
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree   
Reading state information... Done  
E: Unable to locate package mysql-server
```

Tell me what are the possible reason and how to solve it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unable to locate package mysqld-server](http://askubuntu.com/questions/168593/unable-to-locate-package-mysqld-server)

Comment: did you try installing it from ubuntu software center?

Answer (score 0):

**It is because you haven't updated your repositories try this**

```
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get upgrade
  sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Comment: You should improve your answer by explaining what it does and why you think it would solve the problem. Thanks!

Comment: please mark this question as duplicate, instead of posting same answer other questions have.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you will want to update your repository cache.  Always do this before attempting to install or upgrade anything.

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

You can search for packages at this point using `apt-cache` you do *NOT* need root privileges for this:

```
$ apt-cache search mysql-server
```

This will output matching package metadata and simply use `apt-get install` to install it.

Further information you can refer to the manual with `man`.

```
$ man apt-get
$ man apt-cache
```

To learn how to use man you can read the man manual `man man`